# Help with mysql - it fails to restart after the server has no space

Tags: server, mysql

At some point recently, my server disk was full and therefore mysql stopped working. After I did some clean up and the server had enough space again, mysql continune to unable to restart.

```
root@admin:/# service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2022-08-12 10:20:57 CEST; 1s ago
    Process: 2062543 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2062551 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 17 (limit: 38428)
     Memory: 1.8G
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─2062551 /usr/sbin/mysqld

aug 12 10:20:57 admin systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
root@admin:/# service mysql restart
```

Here are most recent error logs from /var/log/mysql/error.log:

```
2022-08-12T08:21:45.072730Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-12T08:21:46.588489Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0 error: 13
2022-08-12T08:21:46.588749Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012894] [InnoDB] Unable to open './#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0' (error: 11).
2022-08-12T08:21:46.588768Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.
2022-08-12T08:21:46.718858Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-12T08:21:46.719078Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-12T08:21:46.719103Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-12T08:21:46.737767Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
2022-08-12T08:21:47.569129Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000081] [Server] option 'thread_cache_size': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 16384.
2022-08-12T08:21:47.574505Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 2063159
2022-08-12T08:21:47.813585Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=2147483648. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2022-08-12T08:21:47.816611Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-12T08:21:49.365445Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0 error: 13
2022-08-12T08:21:49.365718Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012894] [InnoDB] Unable to open './#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0' (error: 11).
2022-08-12T08:21:49.366083Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.
2022-08-12T08:21:49.472341Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-08-12T08:21:49.472574Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-08-12T08:21:49.472605Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-12T08:21:49.491138Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)  (Ubuntu).
```

Can someone tell what is wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed the file permissions for the redo log? 

Comment: @matigo Where is the file located?

Comment: So long as you haven’t modified the location of the data files, all of the InnoDB resources should be located in `/var/lib/mysql/` 

Comment: @matigo This is the file permission:  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67108864 jul 29 07:00 '#ib_redo0'

Answer (score 1):

Having permissions of `root:root` on the MySQL redo directory and files would certainly cause some read issues. These should be `mysql:mysql` as in the directory listing below:

```
drwx------  9 mysql mysql     20480  8月 12 00:00  ./
drwxr-xr-x 77 root  root       4096  7月 14 01:34  ../
...
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql   2359296  8月 12 00:00 '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  10747904  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql      6687  7月 29 06:51  ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 549453824  8月 12 00:00  ibdata1
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  12582912  7月 29 06:52  ibtmp1
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096  7月 29 06:51 '#innodb_redo'/
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096  7月 29 06:51 '#innodb_temp'/
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql      4096  7月 29 06:51  mysql/
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  37748736  7月 29 06:52  mysql.ibd
...
```

```
root@carbon:/var/lib/mysql# ll \#innodb_redo/
total 2097184
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096  7月 29 06:51  ./
drwx------ 9 mysql mysql    20480  8月 12 00:00  ../
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  8月 12 00:00 '#ib_redo0'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo10_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo11_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo12_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo13_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo14_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo15_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo16_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo17_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo18_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo19_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo1_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo20_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo21_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo22_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo23_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo24_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo25_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo26_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo27_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo28_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo29_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo2_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo30_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo31_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo3_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo4_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo5_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo6_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo7_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo8_tmp'
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 67108864  7月 29 06:51 '#ib_redo9_tmp'
```

Note how the permissions here are drastically different from the ones you've listed in your comment. This could point to larger issues with your MySQL files but, for this specific issue, let's get the redo directory and logs corrected:

1. Restore the `'#innodb_redo'` directory permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod 750 /var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** There is no need use `sudo` if you are already set as the super user.</sup>
2. Restore the `#ib_redo` file permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod 640 /var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo/#ib_redo*
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Full paths are used here to reduce the risk of accidentally destroying other parts of the system with permissions changes.</sup>
3. Restart MySQL:

   ```
   sudo service mysql start
   ```

If this was the only directory that had incorrect permissions set, then your database should be operational again. If, however, there are other items in MySQL's data directory that are owned by `root` or have the wrong set of permissions, you may receive a different set of startup errors.